# How to create SVG Gooey effect

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-filters

I am trying to recreate something like [this](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/jmReYr).

This is what I have tried

```js
// targeting the svg itself
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

// variable for the namespace 
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

//vboxDim

var vboxW = 200;
var vboxH = 200;

//assigning svg element attribute 
svg.setAttribute('class', 'layer1');
svg.setAttribute('xmlns', svgns);
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${vboxW} ${vboxH}`);

//make background
var fill1 = 'black';

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute('class', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('id', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute("width", `${vboxW}`);
bg.setAttribute("height", `${vboxH}`);
bg.setAttribute("fill", fill1);

svg.appendChild(bg);

var color = ['white', 'white']
var r = 20;
var cx = (vboxH / 2);
var cy = (vboxW / 2) - 20;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    let circ = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    circ.setAttribute('class', 'crcl' + i);
    circ.setAttribute('id', 'crcl' + i);
    circ.setAttribute("cx", `${cx}`);
    circ.setAttribute("cy", `${cy}`);
    circ.setAttribute("r", r);
    circ.setAttribute("fill", color[i]);
    svg.appendChild(circ);
    r = r - 12;
    cy = cy + .5;


}
```

```css
.crcl0 {
    filter: url(#goo);
}

.crcl1 {
    filter: url(#goo);
    animation: move 5s linear infinite alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-80px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(+80px, 0);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
    <svg>
      <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
    <script href="index.js"></script>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see that it is not creating the desired effect at all. I can't seem to understand why is that. I know in creating a gooey effect the `background color` must be contrasting which I believe is the case above.

Can someone please help me point me to the correct direction as to what am I doing wrong here? Also, I need to admit that I don't understand the math behind the `svg filter` used here. Does that need to be manipulated to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter must affect both shapes at the same time so that they are part of the same "SourceGraphic". To do so, you can use a `<g>` element and add the filter on it:

```js
// targeting the svg itself
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

// variable for the namespace 
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

//vboxDim

var vboxW = 200;
var vboxH = 200;

//assigning svg element attribute 
svg.setAttribute('class', 'layer1');
svg.setAttribute('xmlns', svgns);
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${vboxW} ${vboxH}`);

//make background
var fill1 = 'black';

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute('class', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('id', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute("width", `${vboxW}`);
bg.setAttribute("height", `${vboxH}`);
bg.setAttribute("fill", fill1);

svg.appendChild(bg);

var group = document.createElementNS(svgns, "g");
group.classList.add("gooey");
svg.appendChild(group);

var color = ['white', 'white']
var r = 20;
var cx = (vboxH / 2);
var cy = (vboxW / 2) - 20;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let circ = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
  circ.setAttribute('class', 'crcl' + i);
  circ.setAttribute('id', 'crcl' + i);
  circ.setAttribute("cx", `${cx}`);
  circ.setAttribute("cy", `${cy}`);
  circ.setAttribute("r", r);
  circ.setAttribute("fill", color[i]);
  group.appendChild(circ);
  r = r - 12;
  cy = cy + .5;
}
```

```css
.gooey {
  filter: url(#goo);
}

.crcl1 {
  animation: move 5s linear infinite alternate forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-80px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(+80px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
  <svg>
      <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -10" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
    <script href="index.js"></script>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this and it works. I have a follow-up question. From this solution, I understand that all the elements that I desire to have this effect need to be grouped together and the same filter must be applied to the group. However, in my prod element, there are svg elements (for example, imagine 20 different small circles) that can't be grouped together for other reasons. Can this still be achieved any other way if the grouping deems to be not possible other reasons? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to imagine why the grouping wouldn't be possible. It doesn't need to be in the same <svg>, you can very well apply this filter even on the <body>, though the black <rect> would mess it up.